# Eloquent chunk обрабатывает не все записи laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

У меня есть метод контроллера, состоящий из трех этапов:
 1. Положить данные в бд
 2. Передать сессию данных в скрипт обработки
 3. Отдать данные пользователю

На втором этапе я через модель и условия where хочу перебрать методом chunk 100 записей и каждую из них обработать по окончании итерации ставя записи статус proccess = true. Так вот после работы скрипта у меня есть записи с proccess = false. Как такое может быть, если chunk берет все последовательно и данные не пополняются динамически во время работы скрипта. 
Мой напарник выяснил, что если выделять id обработанной записи в массив, а обновление записей как раз идет по id, а потом уже как chunk все закончить ставить этим записям proccess = true массово, то все записи имеют статус proccess = true.
Как такое может быть ?

```
$model = new customModel();

    $model->where('session', $session)->where('process', false)->chunk(10, function ($datas) use ($model) {
        foreach ($datas as $data) {

            $valid = false;

            if($exp) $valid = true;

            $model->where('id', $data->id)->update([
                'process' => true,
                'valid' => $valid
            ]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это из-за того что в процессе работы с блоками процессов вы их обновляете. Это влияет на конечный результат и даже упоминается в [документации](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#chunking-results):

> If you are updating database records while chunking results, your chunk results could change in unexpected ways. So, when updating records while chunking, it is always best to use the chunkById method instead. This method will automatically paginate the results based on the record's primary key.

И дополнительно к этому (на всякий случай):

> When updating or deleting records inside the chunk callback, any changes to the primary key or foreign keys could affect the chunk query. This could potentially result in records not being included in the chunked results.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!